# PHP Excel esta exportando dados pulando linha

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de ajuda para entender porque ao gerar o relatório os dados não estão batendo com as informações das tags , o mesmo fica pulando linhas

Exemplo de como fica o arquivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
 <?php
$dadosXls = "";
$dadosXls .= "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
$dadosXls .= "<table border='1'>";
$dadosXls .= "<tr>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Cep</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Numero</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Nome</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Endereço</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Numero</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Bairro</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Cidade</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>UF</th>";       
$dadosXls .= "<th>Previsão</th>";
$dadosXls .= "<th>Complemento</th>";      
$dadosXls .= "</tr>";



require_once "../public/setting/conexao.php";

if($_POST){
    session_start();
    $previsao = $_POST["data_entrega"];
}


    try{

        global $previsao;  
        $Conexao    = Conexao::getConnection();
        $query      = $Conexao->query("
        
        select PEDV_CEP, PEDV_ID,
    
        CLI_RAZAO
        
        , PEDV_ENDERECO
        , CLI_NUMERO AS NUMERO
        
        , BAIRRO.GEN_DESC AS BAIRRO
        
        , CIDADE.GEN_DESC AS CIDADE
        
        , UF.GEN_DESC AS UF
        
        , PEDV_DTA_PREV
        
        , PEDV_FLG_ENTREGA
        
        , CLI_COMPLEMENTO_ENT 
        
        from CLIENTE
        
             LEFT JOIN PEDIDO_VENDA ON
        
                                   CLIENTE.CLI_ID = PEDIDO_VENDA.PEDV_CLI_ID 
        
             LEFT JOIN GENER UF ON
        
                                   UF.GEN_TID = 100
        
                   AND UF.GEN_ID  = PEDV_GEN_ID_UF
        
             LEFT JOIN GENER CIDADE ON
        
                                   CIDADE.GEN_TID = 101
        
                   AND CIDADE.GEN_ID  = PEDV_GEN_ID_CIDADE
        
             LEFT JOIN GENER BAIRRO ON
        
                                   BAIRRO.GEN_TID = 102
        
                   AND BAIRRO.GEN_ID  = PEDV_GEN_ID_BAIRRO
        
        WHERE PEDV_FLG_ENTREGA = 'S' AND PEDV_DTA_PREV = '{$previsao}';
        
        
        
        ");
        
        $produtos   = $query->fetchAll();    
    
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    
    foreach($produtos as $produto) {
        $dadosXls .= "<tr>";
        $dadosXls .= '<td>'.$produto['PEDV_CEP'].'<td>';
        $dadosXls .= '<td>'.$produto['PEDV_ID'].'<td>';
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['CLI_RAZAO']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['PEDV_ENDERECO']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['NUMERO']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['BAIRRO']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['CIDADE']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['UF']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['PEDV_DTA_PREV']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "<td>".$produto['CLI_COMPLEMENTO_ENT']."<td>";
        $dadosXls .= "</tr>";
    };

    $dadosXls .= "</table>";

    $arquivo = "PlanilhaEntrega.xls"; 

     // Configurações header para forçar o download  
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$arquivo.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // Se for o IE9, isso talvez seja necessário
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    
    // Envia o conteúdo do arquivo  
    echo $dadosXls;  
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Qual biblioteca você está usando?

Comment: Boa tarde William, não sei se a resposta para a sua pergunta estaria nessas linhas de código:                                                     
      ('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

Comment: então você não está usando nenhuma biblioteca. Me explica melhor o que está acontecendo, o cabeçalho não está batendo com o valor das células? Posta toda a sua página para podermos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Isso mesmo William, os valores não estão batendo com o cabeçalho conforme imagem acima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno, você não está fechando a tag da coluna corretamente com a barra! Você está fazendo `<td>` ao invés de `</td>`.

Troque as linhas de:

`$dadosXls .= '<td>'.$produto['PEDV_CEP'].'<td>';`

para:

`$dadosXls .= '<td>'.$produto['PEDV_CEP'].'</td>';`

Ao encontrar um `<td>` novo antes de fechar com o `</td>` corretamente, o interpretador acha que é outra coluna, fecha o `</td>` e abre o novo. Ai acontece de acrescentar a nova coluna.